# How to bind NSObject<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> in Monotouch?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I am currently trying to map an Objective-C library (sample) to Monotouch. The class is defined as follow:

```
@interface MFSideMenu : NSObject<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

So, when start mapping this inside a Binding library for Monotouch, you would suspect:

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>))]
interface MFSideMenu
{
}
```

But this is not working: The non-generic type 'Monotouch.Foundation.NSObject' cannot be used with the type arguments.

Any ideas how to map this definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to inherit from `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

So use:

`[BaseType(typeof(UIGestureRecognizerDelegate))]`